# How are the objects in the classic single responsibility principle example supposed to communicate?

Tags: python, oop, solid-principles

I'm facing potentially a refactoring project at work and am having a little bit of trouble grasping the single responsibility principle example that shows up on most websites. It is the one regarding separating the connection and send/receive methods of a modem into two different objects. The project is in Python, by the way, but I don't think it is a language-specific issue.

Currently I'm working to break up a 1300 line web service driver class that somebody created (arbitrarily split into two classes but they are essentially one). On the level of responsibility I understand I need to break the connectivity, configuration, and XML manipulation responsibilities into separate classes. Right now all is handled by the class using string manipulations and the `httplib.HTTPConnection` object to handle the request.

So according to this example I would have a class to handle only the http connection, and a class to transfer that data across that connection, but how would these communicate? If I require a connection to be passed in when constructing the data transfer class, does that re-couple the classes?  I'm just having trouble grasping how this transfer class actually accesses the connection that has been made.

Comment: SRP means a class should only change for one reason.  It will likley have to rely on other classes to do it job, but that doesn't change the fact that it has a Single Responsibility, even if it is dependent on other classes. What it really sounds like you are worried about it tight coupling, but that is a Dependency Inversion concern, which is usually tackled with an IoC container.

Answer (score 1):

With a class that huge (> 1000 lines of code) you have more to worry about than only the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) or the [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). I have (or "I fight") classes of similar size and from my experience you have to make unit tests where possible. Carefully refactor (very carefully!) Automatic testing is your friend - be it unit testing as mentioned or regression testing, integration testing, acceptance testing, or whatever you are able to *automatically* execute. Then refactor. And then run the tests. Refactor again. Test. Refactor. Test.

There is a very good book that describes this process: Michael Feather's ["Working Effectively With Legacy Code"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052). Read it.

For example, draw a picture that shows the dependencies of all methods and members of this class. That might help you to identify different "areas" of repsonsibility.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually spent some time working with that book, but had a lot of more pressing readings to be able to get far, unfortunately.  The best part of the refactor is that this is automation code, and it going into a totally new project (to be integrated with previous versions later). Unit testing is part of the new process. Specifically I'm having difficulty understanding how those segregated responsibilities communicate, since the data transfer needs to access the physical connection.